# Black-Scholes formula with expression for strike price

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

I have the ordinary Black-Scholes formula that reads:

$C = S(0) \Phi (d_1) - K e^{-r(T-t_0)}\Phi(d_2)$

Given the following strike price:

$K=e^{r(T-t_0)}S(0)$

I have reduced the above formula as follows:

$C=S(0)\Big[\Phi(d_1)-\Phi(d_2)\Big]$

where $d_1 = \sqrt{T-t_0} \Big(\frac{2r-1/2 \sigma^{2}}{\sigma}\Big)$ and $d_2 = \sqrt{T-t_0} \Big(\frac{2r+1/2 \sigma^{2}}{\sigma}\Big)$

Is a further reduction in terms of the cumulative distribution function operation possible?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the stochastic PDE in this question?

Comment: It is a standard Black-Scholes PDE. I reckon you do not need it to further cut down the formula.

Comment: Black Scholes is not a stochastic PDE it is a deterministic PDE.